# Mocking scala method with functional parameter using Mockito

Tags: postgresql, scala, unit-testing, mockito, finagle

Working with Finatra and trying to mock a database call for testing.  I'm using `finagle-postgres` which defines this method:

```
def prepareAndQuery[T](sql: String, params: Any*)(f: Row => T): Future[Seq[T]] = {...}
```

Other mocks using `Mockito` have been straightforward. But, I can't seem to get this one to work.  After struggling with the compiler I finally found this, but it doesn't work at run-time:

```
case class Foo( a: Int, b: Int, c: Int )
val client = smartMock[Client]
def f(row:Row): Foo = {
  Foo(1,2,3)
}
client.prepareAndQuery[Foo]("select 1") returns { x => f(x) }
```

Executing the test throws:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.SmartNullPointerException: 
...
because this method call was *not* stubbed correctly:
```

I'm new to Mockito and I haven't found an example of mocking a function that takes a function parameter.  Any thoughts on how my mock is wrong?

Comment: If you want to unit test/mock with a persistence layer based on JDBC, on can have a look at http://tour.acolyte.eu.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna a straightforward stub of that method then you could do something like

```
val client = mock[Client]
when(client.prepareAndQuery[Foo](any, any)(any)) thenReturn Future.successful(<whatever you want>)
```

that would return `<whatever you want>` no matter what

Answer (score -2):

I would say that using any "mocking" framework is a red flag in scala.
Ideally you should be able "mock" by providing your own implementation of the client.

```
class MockMysqlClient extends Client {
...
}
```

Just override/implement the methods that are supposed to return the value from the DB.

Comment: mockito is a standard mocking framework that is used in scala. Plenty of scenarios where you would want to mock or spy a Scala class